# React Table: pasar parámetro a un componente dentro de una Cell de una columna

Tags: reactjs

Estoy creando una tabla donde estoy definiendo las columnas en una constante de este modo. Necesito saber cómo podría pasarle al componente Hover de Cell el parámetro indicado como ID que me llega como accesor. Es posible?
La finalidad es crear un botón de borrado para esa ID. Alguna sugerencia?

```
const cols = React.useMemo(
  () => [
      { Header: "Sociedad", accessor: "sociedad" },
      { Header: "Identificador", accessor: "ID" },
      { Header: "acciones", accessor: "actions", Cell: () => <Hover ide={xxxxIDxxxxx} />},
    ],
  []
);
```

Answer (score 1):

He encontrado una manera que me funciona y es la siguiente, añadiendo un id de columna cualquiera para que no dé fallo:

```
 {
    Header: "Acciones",
    accessor: (row) => `${row.ID}`,
    id: "paramGet",
    Cell: (accessor) => <Hover ide={accessor.value} />,
  },
```